# Is Apache significantly slower at checking passwords hashed with bcrypt than php's password_verify is?

Tags: php, apache, hash, bcrypt

I've been working with upgrading a website's security which includes using bcrypt to hash the passwords. So far everything on the php end is working perfectly. I ended up using 12 rounds, which works out to be about 0.25 seconds to verify a password in php.

However, this website's admin section uses a .htpasswd file to authenticate users who wish to access the administration tools. The website takes the hash values from the database a few times per day via cron job and places them in the .htpasswd file for those who have admin access. Apache supports bcrypt as of version 2.4, and it does in fact work. The problem is that the same hash that I'm using in php takes roughly 25-30 seconds to verify in Apache. The previous use of md5 was almost instantaneous, which would suggest it is the fact that bcrypt is designed to be slow that is causing the issue rather than some kind of connection or setting issue.

Is Apache just simply that slow at verifying a bcrypt password compared to php, or is there some kind of throttle setting that I'm missing in Apache on top of the built in bcrypt delay?

**EDIT:** On further testing, the slowness is definitely being caused by the number of rounds in the bcrypt hash. I still don't understand why it would be any different than php running on the same server, so any insight as to why this is would be excellent, so to officially edit my question, why is Apache slower?

Comment: Have you determined if the admin is overriding the -C "computing time" argument in the cron job to hash the passwords?  It is documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: @StuartCarnie The cron job is not actually hashing the passwords. It is grabbing the hashed passwords from a mySQL database where they have already been hashed with a cost of 12. The -C argument only appears to apply if Apache is in charge of doing the initial hashing, as far as I can tell anyway.